# PowerShellで正規表現にマッチしたすべての箇所を配列に入れたい

Tags: 正規表現, powershell

以下のような条件があるとして、マッチしたカッコの中身を配列に入れたいです。
PowerShellでどのように実現したらいいでしょうか？

**条件:**

```
$data = "{ab},{cd},{ef}・・・・" # この長さは固定ではなく可変
$regex = '{(.+?)}'
```

**期待する結果:**

```
$array[0] = "ab" 
$array[1] = "bc" 
$array[2] = "ef"
```

※備考
PowerShellだと配列に入れるというような考え方は無いのかもしれませんが、
昔、Perlでこういうものは配列に入れたほうが後で処理しやすかったので、
PowerShellでも実現したいのです。

Comment: `{ }`の中の文字列に`,`が入っている可能性や、閉じ`}`と開き`{`の間に`,`以外の文字が入っている可能性はありますか？ 入っているとしたらどのようなものが考えられるでしょう？ その辺の詳細を追記してみてください。 内容に依っては正規表現ではなく split, replace で出来そうな感じですが。

Comment: データは「{ ～ },{ ～ },{ ～ },......」という形式です。そして、～の間には、英数字だけでなく、カンマ「,」や、コロン「:」、ダブルクォーテーション「"」、ピリオド「.」UTF-8の日本語が含まれています。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[regex]::Matches`を使うことで、マッチ結果をコレクション(≒配列)として取得できます。

**サンプルコード**

```
$data = "{ab},{cd},{ef}・・・・" #この長さは固定ではなく、可変です。
$regex = '{(.+?)}'

$ms = [regex]::Matches($data, $regex)   # この時点でマッチがコレクションとして取得できる
$array = ($ms | %{$_.Groups[1].Value})  # ()内の文字列をグループの値としてコレクション化して $array 変数に入れる
$array                                  # 表示
```

Comment: 実行したところ、このコードで、期待する結果が得られたようです。大変助かりました。

Answer (score 2):

基本的にはpayanecoさんの回答通りなのですが、正規表現をもう少し工夫すると、PowerShell側から簡単にアクセスできるようになります。

```
$data = "{ab},{cd},{ef}・・・・" #この長さは固定ではなく、可変です。
$regex = '(?<={).+?(?=})'

$ms = [regex]::Matches($data, $regex)   # この時点でマッチがコレクションとして取得できる
$ms.Value                               # 表示
```

これは、[メンバーアクセス演算子](https://learn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration?view=powershell-7.3)といって、存在しないメンバーにアクセスした際、自動的に各要素のメンバーにアクセスしてくれる機能です。
つまり、`$ms`は`[Regex]::Matches()`の戻り値である`MatchCollection`であり、`$ms.Value`は`MatchCollection`に`Value`プロパティが存在しないため、`$ms | ForEach-Object { $_.Value }` として機能します。

（payanecoさんの回答では、`.Groups`まではこの機能が使えますが、`[1]`の時点で存在するメンバーとなってしまい、2番目の要素が取得されてしまいます。このため、`.Value`でアクセスできるように正規表現を工夫する必要がありました。）

---

> 配列にどのように格納したらよいでしょうか？

`$ms.Value.GetType()`を実行すれば

```
PS> $ms.Value.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

と得られるように、`$ms.Value`が既に配列です。格納したい場所に代入してください。

Comment: $ms.Value を実行した時点で、ab,cd,efの3つに分割することは確認できましたが、配列にどのように格納したらよいでしょうか？

Comment: @bew3g3hjjj 加筆しました。